# Why is the override not working properly?

Tags: android, file, camera, overriding

I was looking at a tutorial, this one to be exact - http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/01/start-camera-auto-focusing-autofocus.html

And I downloaded the files the author provided, and when i added them into eclipse, I got errors all over the place, and when I click each one it is saying remove the @override, and when I do it is error free, but the actual application wouldn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the "source compliance mode" in eclipse to 6 or higher. In older versions of java, the @Override annotation was not valid on method from an interface (only in those actually defined in a parent class). Open the Window > Preferences dialog, and browse to Java > Compiler. There you can set the "Compiler compliance level" to 1.6.

Comment: I changed it, and it still kept them the same, still the same error. It was set at 1.7

Comment: make sure you also set the "Source Compatibility" to 1.7 ... you should also ensure that your project isn't using project-specific settings (right-click your project and select "Properties" and then navigate to the same Java Compiler preference pane). If you are using project-specific settings, set the source compliance level to 1.7 there too.

Comment: Ha, thanks right when I looked back I saw project specific, Your a beast, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have "something" in your "gen" folder? If you havent is because the ADT plugin is not working (you'll find this pretty often)

**First:**
 - Click on "Project" on the menu bar"

- Click on "Clean..."
- Select your project
- Click Ok

**If it didnt work try this:**

- Right click on your project -> Delete (make sure NOT to check the "delete files on disk" option)
- New Project -> Android Project -> Create from existing Source (specify source)

**If the second method didnt work** try repeating it. Some times works the second or thrid time